# how to implement Persistent storage in android

Tags: android, remember-me

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Persistent Data Storage in Android Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772147/persistent-data-storage-in-android-development)

I want to implement persistent storage in my application to store the UserName, when the user selects "Remember me" Checkbox. Can anybody guide me for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use shared preferences for this purpose. Shared preferences store information until the app gets uninstalled. [This blog post](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.com/2011/06/shared-preferences-persistent-storage.html) gives an example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very interesting and official article about that on the [Android's website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). I suggest starting by reading it.

This article will show you the various storage options and their intended usage. And for each option, it gives you some example code.

The [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) is of course covered by this article.

Comment: When a link to useful information in an answer dies, the answer becomes useless. You can help by extracting useful information into your answer.